# Pass arguments with App engine launcher

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I needs to pass two arguments using App Engine Launcher like this:

```
localhost:8080/?input1=test1&input2=test2.
```

I think that I should use: EDIT, APPLICATION SETTINGS? Is correct?
What's the syntax?